# Python, A MySQL statement works when I put in actual value of variable, but not when using variable?

Tags: python, mysql, stdin

Have the following code, it is part of a script used to read stdin, and process logs.

```
jobId = loglist[19]
deliveryCount += 1
dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + %s WHERE id = %s') % (deliveryCount,jobId)
dbcon.commit()
dbcon.close()
```

I can run the following:

```
dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + 1 WHERE id=1')
dbcon.commit()
dbcon.close()
```

and it will work.  Not really sure whats going on, and its hard for me to test quickly because I can't actually see the script running since my program feeds directly into it.  I have to make changes, restart program that feeds, send an email, then check database.  Have other scripts, and am able to use variables in SQL statements with no problem.

Any suggestions as to what may be going on?  And, any suggestions on how I can test quicker?

full code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import MySQLdb
import csv

if __name__=="__main__":

dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(host="tattoine.mktrn.net", port=3306, user="adki", passwd="pKhL9vrMN8BsFrJ5", db="adki")
dbcur = dbcon.cursor()

    #type, timeLogged,timeQueued,orig,rcpt,orcpt,dsnAction,dsnStatus,dsnDiag,dsnMta,bounceCat,srcType,srcMta,dlvType,dlvSourceIp,dlvDestinationIp,dlvEsmtpAvailable,dlvSize,vmta,jobId,envId,queue,vmtaPool
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    fwrite = open("debug.log","w")
   # fwrite.write(str(deliveryCount))
    fwrite.write("test2")
    dbcur.execute("INSERT INTO test(event_type) VALUES ('list')")
    dbcon.commit()

    loglist = line.split(',')



    deliveryCount = 0
    bounceType = loglist[0]
    bounceCategory = loglist[10]
    email = loglist[4]
    jobId = loglist[19]

    if bounceType == 'd':
        deliveryCount += 1


fwrite = open("debug2.log","w")
   # fwrite.write(str(deliveryCount))
fwrite.write("test3")

dbcur.execute("INSERT INTO test(event_type) VALUES (%d)", deliveryCount)
dbcon.commit()
dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + %s WHERE id = %s',(deliveryCount,jobId))
dbcon.commit()
dbcon.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use string interpolation to run a sql query.

You should do:

```
dbcur.execute(
    'UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + %s WHERE id = %s',
    (deliveryCount,jobId)
)
```

There's two arguments to the execute function. The query with placeholders, and a tuple of parameters. This way, mysql will escape your parameters for you and prevent sql injection attacks ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection )

Your error must have come from the fact that you use the % operator on the result of the query `'UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + %s WHERE id = %s'`. This query in itself (without parameters) is syntactically incorrect for mysql. You have to pass the tuple of parameters to the execute function as a second argument.

Comment: still getting blank, any idea?

Comment: I think its possible I'm never escaping the 'while true' statement, as I never get 'test3' written to my debug file.  But thank you for letting me know correct way I should be doing sql.

Comment: @brizz Only use the %s placeholder (not %d). Also, the second argument to the `execute` method must always be a **tuple**, even if your query has only one parameter. Like this: dbcur.execute("INSERT INTO test(event_type) VALUES (%s)", (deliveryCount,))